# I want to stop gmail messages appearing on my screen as soon as I log on

Tags: macos

When I put my password into my mac and log on I get my gmail screen with its messages appearing together with other items how do i stop this happening. I am using OSX version 10.8.5  Thank you IR.

Comment: When I log on and enter my password the whole screen then

Comment: displays all my current gmail menages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are these messages appearing via Notification Center, in the upper right of your display?

Comment: Answer or comment?

Comment: The original question isn't incredibly descriptive, I'm trying to clarify the problem statement.

Comment: Which is usually reserved for comments. It tricks people like me. I normally don't click on questions with answers in them for this site since answers are usually one-sided with AskDifferent

Comment: Are you saying the "add a comment" section is typically used for questions like mine, to clarify the post, and the "answer" section is used for potential answers?  I promise I'm not trying to be a smart aleck, I really wasn't aware of the difference.

Comment: Yes indeed - that's the general premise, especially since you have enough reputation to post a comment, and I didn't take it as you being a smart aleck. See [improve posts section](http://apple.stackexchange.com/tour)